# validity of input field using span

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create an input field with front-end validation. The idea is that when the user types in the password and unfocuses the input field, depending on the criteria that are not met the corresponding span will become red. As soon as they edit the input, if the criteria are met, they will return to the original color. How do I achieve this? I am attaching part of my code.

```js
const inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('.common-input-class');

inputFields.forEach(function(inputField) {
  const errorMessage = inputField.parentElement.querySelector('.error-message');
  let hasError = false; //variable to track the input error state

  inputField.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    if (inputField.value.trim() === '') {
      inputField.style.border = '1.7px solid red';
      errorMessage.style.display = 'block';
      hasError = true;
    } else {
      inputField.style.border = '1.2px solid #ccc';
      errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
      hasError = false; // Reset the error state when unfocused
    }
  });

  inputField.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (hasError) {
      inputField.style.border = '1.7px solid red';
      errorMessage.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      inputField.style.border = '1.2px solid #ccc'; // Reset the border color on input
      errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});

const passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');
const passwordErrorMessage = document.querySelector('.nenp .error-message');
const nenpDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.nenp');
let passwordHasError = false; //variable to track the password error state

passwordInput.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  if (passwordInput.value.trim() === '') {
    passwordInput.closest('.password').style.border = '1.7px solid red';
    passwordErrorMessage.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    const span1 = nenpDivs[0].querySelector('span:nth-child(1)');
    const span2 = nenpDivs[0].querySelector('span:nth-child(2)');

    if (span1.style.color === 'red' || span2.style.color === 'red') {
      passwordInput.closest('.password').style.border = '1.7px solid red';
      passwordHasError = true;
    } else {
      passwordInput.closest('.password').style.border = '1.2px solid #ccc';
      passwordErrorMessage.style.display = 'none';
      passwordHasError = false; // Reset the error state when unfocused
    }
  }
});

passwordInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
  const inputValue = passwordInput.value.trim();

  nenpDivs.forEach(function(nenpDiv) {
    const span1 = nenpDiv.querySelector('span:nth-child(1)');
    const span2 = nenpDiv.querySelector('span:nth-child(2)');

    if (inputValue.length < 8) {
      span1.style.color = 'red'; // Change to red when the criteria are not met
      passwordHasError = true;
    } else {
      span1.style.color = ''; // Reset to the original color when the criteria are met
    }

    if (/[A-Z]/.test(inputValue) && /\d/.test(inputValue)) {
      span2.style.color = ''; // Reset to the original color when the criteria are met
      passwordHasError = false; // Reset the error state when the criteria are met
    } else {
      span2.style.color = 'red'; // Change to red when the criteria are not met
      passwordHasError = true;
    }
  });
});

// Add a blur event listener to passwordInput to set passwordHasError when it loses focus
passwordInput.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  if (passwordHasError) {
    passwordInput.closest('.password').style.border = '1.7px solid red';
  } else {
    passwordInput.closest('.password').style.border = '1.2px solid #ccc';
  }
});
```

```css
.error-message {
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(251, 70, 34);
  margin-top: -27px;
  margin-left: 14px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-form nenp">
  <label for="number">Password </label>
  <div class="password">

    <input type="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" required>
    <div class="visibility">
      <a>eye</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <span class="error-message">required</span>
  <div style="margin-top: -10px; display: grid;">
    <span>Minimum 6 characters</span>
    <span>Must include an Uppercase and number </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your text says 6 characters but the code says `f (inputValue.length < 8)` which is correct?

Comment: hey, its a typo. supposed to be 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it that way, you just have to adjust it to your criteria

```js
const passwordInput = document.getElementById('passwordInput');
const lengthValidation = document.getElementById('lengthValidation');
const uppercaseValidation = document.getElementById('uppercaseValidation');
const numberValidation = document.getElementById('numberValidation');

function validatePassword() {
  const password = passwordInput.value;

  // Check criteria and change colors accordingly
  if (password.length >= 8) {
    lengthValidation.classList.remove('error'); // Criteria met
  } else {
    lengthValidation.classList.add('error'); // Criteria not met
  }

  if (/[A-Z]/.test(password)) {
    uppercaseValidation.classList.remove('error'); // Criteria met
  } else {
    uppercaseValidation.classList.add('error'); // Criteria not met
  }

  if (/\d/.test(password)) {
    numberValidation.classList.remove('error'); // Criteria met
  } else {
    numberValidation.classList.add('error'); // Criteria not met
  }
}

function checkWhileWriting() {
  const password = passwordInput.value;

  // Check criteria and change colors accordingly
  if (password.length >= 8) {
    lengthValidation.classList.remove('error'); // Criteria met
  }

  if (/[A-Z]/.test(password)) {
    uppercaseValidation.classList.remove('error'); // Criteria met
  }

  if (/\d/.test(password)) {
    numberValidation.classList.remove('error'); // Criteria met
  }
}
passwordInput.addEventListener('blur', validatePassword);

// Add an input event listener to check criteria while typing
passwordInput.addEventListener('input', checkWhileWriting);
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  /* Color when criteria are not met */
}
```

```html
<label for="passwordInput">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="passwordInput">
<br>
<span id="lengthValidation">Password must be at least 8 characters long</span>
<br>
<span id="uppercaseValidation">Password must contain at least one uppercase letter</span>
<br>
<span id="numberValidation">Password must contain at least one number</span>
```

Comment: hey, even with your code, the spans are turning red as soon as I enter a char. I want the validation to wait until I unfocus the input field (basically validation after the user has typed all the text)

Comment: @kangkong
I edited the message, I think I understood you correctly now, the test can be divided into 2 functions, one checks and can turn the text red, and the other only checks if the text meets the condition now

Comment: hey @postFix, Thanks for the help. Is it possible to include to the span the validation responsive to even when the user backspaces/deletes the text?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I saw your code and it's a bit messy to understand at first, but the idea was there, **Keep it up!**

I got inspired by how it worked and created this, where the code is less repetitive, more readable and easy to change.

**Before you see the code be aware that:** This code use JS that add classes to items that are being stylized with CSS. To change any of the looks depending on what you want, just change the CSS. Basically JS is linked with CSS.

> **Hope this helps! :)**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Password Verify</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="WrapDiv">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <div class="password">
        <input type="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" required />
        <div class="visibility"><a>eye</a></div>
      </div>

      <span class="ErrorMessage">Required</span>
      <div class="RequiredForPassword">
        <span>Minimum 6 characters</span>
        <span>Must include an Uppercase and number</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="Code.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Style.css

```
/* password input */
.password {
  display: grid;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

/* visibility button 'eye' */
.visibility {
  width: fit-content;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* RequiredForPassword attributes */
.RequiredForPassword {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

/* Error */
.Error {
  border: 1.7px solid red;
}

/* ErrorMessage ('required') */
.ErrorMessage {
  display: none;
}

/* 
  if(.password child that has a class of 'Empty'){
    get the sibling element that have a class of 'ErrorMessage'
  }
*/
.password:has(> .Empty) + .ErrorMessage {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

/* 
  if(.password child that has a class of 'Error'){
    get the sibling element that have a class of 'RequiredForPassword'
  }
*/
.password:has(> .Error) + .RequiredForPassword {
  color: rebeccapurple !important;
}

/* RequiredForPasswordError */
.RequiredForPasswordError {
  color: red;
}
```

Code.js

```
var Password = document.getElementById("password"); // Get password input
var WrapDiv = document.getElementById("WrapDiv"); // Get password whole wrap div
var HasError = false; // Input has error

var WaitToValidate = ""; // Setup for timer
var OldLetter = null; // See the old letter typed

// Get the 1° RequiredForPassword span
const span1 = WrapDiv.querySelector(".RequiredForPassword :nth-child(1)");

// Get the 2° RequiredForPassword span
const span2 = WrapDiv.querySelector(".RequiredForPassword :nth-child(2)");

// When input is unfocused
Password.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  // Check if password value it's empty
  if (Password.value.trim() === "") {
    // If it is style the input with css by class
    Password.classList.add("Error");

    // Add the class when input is empty
    Password.classList.add("Empty");
    HasError = true;
  } else {
    // If it is not empty, remove the style of input with css by class
    Password.classList.remove("Empty");

    // Remove the class when input is not empty
    Password.classList.remove("Error");
    HasError = true;
  }
});

Password.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  clearTimeout(WaitToValidate); // Clear timeout

  // If the user is deleting and the value of the input is empty
  if (e.inputType == "deleteContentBackward" && Password.value.trim() == "") {
    // Validade, to show 'required'
    Validate();
    // If the user is typing something and the old value of the input is was empty
  } else if (e.inputType == "insertText" && OldLetter == "") {
    // Validade, to remove the 'required'
    Validate();

    span1.classList.remove("RequiredForPasswordError");
    span2.classList.remove("RequiredForPasswordError");
  } else {
    /*
      If the user types something, wait a second (1000 miliseconds) until validating

      The timeout will clear if the user types something before the 1 second timeout,
      as seen in the 'clearTimeout(WaitToValidate);'
    */

    WaitToValidate = setTimeout(() => {
      Validate();
    }, 1000);

    // To change the time after the user finished writing, change the number. It's in miliseconds (ms)
    // 1 second = 1000 miliseconds
    // 0.5 seconds = 500 ms
  }

  OldLetter = Password.value.trim();
});

function Validate() {
  const PasswordValue = Password.value.trim(); // Get Password value and save in a variable

  // Check password value if it's empty
  if (PasswordValue === "") {
    // If it is add the class when input is empty
    Password.classList.add("Empty");
    span1.classList.add("RequiredForPasswordError");
    span2.classList.add("RequiredForPasswordError");
    HasError = true;
  } else {
    // If it is not empty, remove the class when input is not empty
    Password.classList.remove("Empty");

    HasError = false;

    // To optimize the code, remove unecessary checks when the password is empty

    // If the input value has a lenght less than 6
    if (PasswordValue.length < 6) {
      // Make the 1° required item be stylized with a class
      span1.classList.add("RequiredForPasswordError");
      HasError = true;
    } else {
      // Else if the input value has a lenght more or equal than 6
      // Remove the 1° required item class
      span1.classList.remove("RequiredForPasswordError");
    }

    // If the input has Uppercase letter AND number
    if (/[A-Z]/g.test(PasswordValue) && /\d/g.test(PasswordValue)) {
      // Remove the 2° required item class
      span2.classList.remove("RequiredForPasswordError");
      HasError = false;
    } else {
      // Else if the input has Uppercase letter OR number OR etheir
      // Make the 2° required item be stylized with a class
      span2.classList.add("RequiredForPasswordError");
      HasError = true;
    }
  }

  // If there is error
  if (HasError) {
    // Make the Password input be stylized with a class
    Password.classList.add("Error");
  } else {
    // Remove the Password input class
    Password.classList.remove("Error");
  }
}
```

**[ Edited ]**
**How it works:**

In js there is a functionality where you can delay the execution of things, you can do it by using the **timeout** funcion by vanilla JS.

> setTimeout(**function**, **timeInMS**);

```
setTimeout(() => {
    // Execute after 1000ms
}, 1000);
```

You can use it as this too!

```
setTimeout(myfunc, 1000);

function myfunc(){
  alert('hello!');
}
```

To clear a time out, you have to save it in a variable, otherwise it will give an error

First save the time out in a variable

```
let MyTimeOut = setTimeout(() => {
    // Execute after 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

Secondly when you want to stop it, just type

```
clearTimeout(MyTimeOut);
```

> clearTimeout(**TIMEOUTNAME**);

Comment: hey, thanks for the feedback. I'll try to keep my code more structured in the future. The problem I am facing with your code is the same problem I have in my code. The error texts are turning red as soon as I enter a char. I want the validation to wait until the user finishes typing (using unfocus of input field as proxy for this )

Comment: Okay, i'm going to do that.. sorry for not making what you wanted :P

Comment: I edited the code, see it it's what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

For that,

I can do it with this kind of validation.

```js
var passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');
var msg = document.getElementById("error-message");
var text_required = document.getElementById("required");
var text_length = document.getElementById("length");
var text_case = document.getElementById("no-uppercase");
var text_number = document.getElementById("no-number");

function submit(){
    if(passwordInput.value && text_required.style.display != "block" && text_length.style.display != "block" && text_case.style.display != "block" && text_number.style.display != "block"){
        alert('Form is submitted!');
    }else{
        validation();
    }
}

function validation(){
    let valueIsNull =  Boolean(passwordInput.value == '' || passwordInput.value == null);
    let notMinimumCharacter = Boolean(passwordInput.value.length < 6);
    let notUpperCase = Boolean(!(/[A-Z]/.test(passwordInput.value)));
    let noNumber = Boolean(!(/[0-9]/.test(passwordInput.value)));
    passwordInput.style.borderColor = valueIsNull || notMinimumCharacter || notUpperCase || noNumber ? "red" : "black";
    valueIsNull ? [text_required.style.display = "block",text_required.style.color = "red"]  : text_required.style.color = "black";
    notMinimumCharacter ? [text_length.style.display = "block",text_length.style.color = "red"] : text_length.style.color = "black";
    notUpperCase ? [text_case.style.display = "block",text_case.style.color = "red"] : text_case.style.color = "black";
    noNumber ? [text_number.style.display = "block",text_number.style.color = "red"] : text_number.style.color = "black";
    !valueIsNull ? text_required.style.display = "none" : text_required.style.display = "block"
    !notMinimumCharacter ? text_length.style.display = "none" : text_length.style.display = "block"
    !notUpperCase ? text_case.style.display = "none" : text_case.style.display = "block"
    !noNumber ? text_number.style.display = "none" : text_number.style.display = "block"
    if(!valueIsNull && !notMinimumCharacter && !notUpperCase && !noNumber){
        text_required.style.display = "none";
        text_length.style.display = "none";
        text_case.style.display = "none";
        text_number.style.display = "none";
    }
}

passwordInput.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    validation();
});

passwordInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    let valueIsNull =  Boolean(passwordInput.value != '' || passwordInput.value != null);
    let notMinimumCharacter = Boolean(passwordInput.value.length > 5);
    let notUpperCase = Boolean(/[A-Z]/.test(passwordInput.value));
    let noNumber = Boolean(/[0-9]/.test(passwordInput.value));
    if(event.key === "Backspace" || event.key === "Delete" ){
        let valueIsNull =  Boolean(passwordInput.value == '' || passwordInput.value == null);
        let notMinimumCharacter = Boolean(passwordInput.value.length < 6);
        let notUpperCase = Boolean(!(/[A-Z]/.test(passwordInput.value)));
        let noNumber = Boolean(!(/[0-9]/.test(passwordInput.value)));
        passwordInput.style.borderColor = valueIsNull || notMinimumCharacter || notUpperCase || noNumber ? "red" : "black";
        valueIsNull ? text_required.style.color = "red"  : text_required.style.color = "black";
        notMinimumCharacter ? text_length.style.color = "red" : text_length.style.color = "black";
        notUpperCase ? text_case.style.color = "red" : text_case.style.color = "black";
        noNumber ? text_number.style.color = "red" : text_number.style.color = "black";
    }else{
        valueIsNull ? text_required.style.color = "black" : text_required.style.color = "red";
        notMinimumCharacter ? text_length.style.color = "black" : text_length.style.color = "red";
        notUpperCase ? text_case.style.color = "black" : text_case.style.color = "red";
        noNumber ? text_number.style.color = "black" : text_number.style.color = "red";
    }
});
```

```css
span{
   display:none;
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-form nenp">
    <label for="number">Password </label>
    <div class="password">
        <input type="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" required>
    </div>
    <div id="error-message" style="display:grid;">
        <span id="required">Required</span>
        <span id="length">Minimum 6 characters</span>
        <span id="no-uppercase">Must include an Uppercase</span>
        <span id="no-number">Must have a number</span>
    </div>
    <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Hope I could help you.

So, you can use or refer to this one. :)

Comment: hey @newbee, thanks for the help. I am unable to make few changes in your code to make it fit into my code. Hope you can help me with that. 

The change I want is- I want span mini 6 char and the 2 below that to be visible all the time. I changed the display style in the code but the problem is, the spans are turning red as soon as I enter text. Is it possible for them to be red only after unfocusing the input field?

Comment: @kangkong - I was late. Your request is possible, but you already accepted best answer, so changing my code seems to be useless anymore. Do you still need it?